# Remove milliseconds from logs in Unix

Tags: unix

We have a log file with below format:

```
22:59:59.372 test1 operation1
22:59:59.372 test2 operation2
22:59:59.359 test3 operation3
22:59:59.359 test4 operation4
```

We want to strip the milliseconds and achieve an out as below:

```
22:59:59 test1 operation1
22:59:59 test2 operation2
22:59:59 test3 operation3
22:59:59 test4 operation4
```

Could you please help me with a unix command to achieve this.

Comment: So what have you done to try and accomplish this yourself? Any one of sed/awk/perl/etc... could do this...

Comment: Please show some effort and post what you have tried so far. StackOverflow is not a code writing service, and questions like this are normally not well accepted. Posting a good question, on the other hand, makes it much more likely to result in the answers you are looking for. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Guys, I had to get this information out of a large log file whose format is as below: Jan  6 23:00:00 devicename Wed: Jan 06 2016 22:59:59.372 [info][domain][service][response] tid:(103487661) | TransactionID: 75e06d8a-97ae-47a9-8c79-0ff7c3d005b3 | ConsumerID: TEST | providerID: Organization | applicationID: test1 | originatorIP: 1.2.3.4 | Operation: operation1 | Destination: https:1.2.3.4 | Time Elapsed: 678      The files which contain these logs are of around 5 GB each. I need to find out the combination of unique timestamp in seconds with operation and application id.

Comment: To find out these unique combinations I have used the cut command(cut -d ' ' -f 10,24,30) but it can take only one delimiter at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe to:

```
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/^(.{7})...(.*)/$1$2/; print $_'
```

Like:

```
 cat /tmp/in.txt | perl -ne '$_ =~ s/^(.{7})...(.*)/$1$2/; print $_'
```

or:

```
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/^(.{7})...(.*)/$1$2/; print $_' < /tmp/in.txt
```